# SQL job fails with "Log In failed for user X, error 18456"

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, linked-server

I have two servers (**A**, **B**) linked together. On **server A** I have a stored procedure that accesses a table found on **server B**. I am accessing the table in the following fashion:

```
SELECT 
    LoggedAt,
    ReturnDuration
FROM [serverB].[databaseName].[dbo].[tableName]
WHERE LoggedAt BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime
    AND ReturnDuration IS NOT NULL
```

The job is a single line that invokes the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[storedProcedureName]
```

When running the stored procedure manually, it succeeds without any errors. However, when I put the stored procedure in a job and attempt to execute it, I get the following error messages:

1. The job failed. The job was invoked by User domainName\userName. The last step to run was step 1 (stepName). The job was requested to start at step 1 (stepName).
2. Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. Login failed for user domainName\SQL01AGENT. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18456). The step failed.

Looking for help online, I managed to discover the error may be due to domainName\SQL01AGENT not being added as a valid login on **server B**. After adding that login and granting it the correct user mappings (mapped to my database on **server B** with db_datareader, db_dataowner and public roles) with Login status set to enabled, the job still failed with the same error.

Another solution I found was to run the step as myself instead of the server agent. However that gave me a different error that "Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15274). The step failed."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already you might ask your DBA to add a linked server to ServerB under Server Objects -> Linked Servers

Comment: Its already added but since I was the one who did it and not the DBA, I might ask him to do it for me as it is possible I missed some details when doing so.